# Figuring out how to update my label in javaFX to match the analog clock

Tags: javafx

I am trying to figure out how to make the label update and display the current time like the analog clock is thank you in advance. For some reason this site won't let me post unless I make a long drawn out explanation that is full of words. Either that or you have to be much smarter than I am in order to use the site. I hope this is wordy enough.

```
public class Homework7 extends Application {

  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Create a clock and a label
    ClockPane clock = new ClockPane();
    String timeString = clock.getHour() + ":" + clock.getMinute() 
      + ":" + clock.getSecond();
    Label lblCurrentTime = new Label(timeString);


    // Place clock and label in border pane
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(clock);
    pane.setBottom(lblCurrentTime);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(lblCurrentTime, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 250, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Christian Beckman"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

    // Create a handler for animation
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = e -> {
      clock.setCurrentTime(); // Set a new clock time
    };

    // Create an animation for a running clock
    Timeline animation = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), eventHandler));
    animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animation.play(); // Start animation

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    // Scene scene = new Scene(clock, 250, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Christian Beckman"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update the `Label` text after updating the clock:

```
...
EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = e -> {
    clock.setCurrentTime(); // Set a new clock time
    update(lblCurrentTime, clock);
};
...


private static void update(Label label, Clock clock) {
     String text = ...;
     label.setText(text);
}
```

If the `ClockPane` class returns correctly formatted `String`s (e.g. `"07"` for seconds = 7) simply compute the text as in the initialization of the `Label` text:

```
 String text = clock.getHour() + ":" + clock.getMinute() + ":" + clock.getSecond();
```

If those methods return `int`s, you could use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
```

```
String text = LocalTime.of(clock.getHour(), clock.getMinute(), clock.getSecond()).format(FORMATTER);
```